# Dask-cuDF to CuDF dataframe conversion

Tags: dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe, rapids, cudf

Is there any function, that convert Dask-cudf dataframe to Cudf dataframe?Like from_cudf for cudf to dask-cudf.
dgdf = dask_cudf.from_cudf(df, npartitions=2)

Answer (score 1):

Running `.compute()` method on a `dask_cudf.DataFrame` will convert it to a `cudf.DataFrame`:

```py
df_cudf = df_dask_cudf.compute()
```